# Problems installing MATLAB - Scientific computing environment

Tags: matlab

I have problems completing a MATLAB installation.

I downloaded the installation files from mathworks.com and I ran the installation as root, so far so good. The problem is that I am unable to install the "MATLAB - Scientific computing environment" from the software center. When I try to do the installation I get the error message "No MATLAB executables were found in the directories you specified. This package requires at least one local installation of MATLAB."

I thought that the problem would be solved by creating a matlab link under usr/local/bin. This enabled opening matlab independent of location, but I can still not install "MATLAB - Scientific computing environment".

Comment: Are you able to start matlab from the terminal? The install from the software center provides icons, but you should still be able to run matlab from the shell. If you can't, that gives some indication of where to start debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install matlab-support`. You will see the following screen:

[image]

Follow the instructions - enter the directory where you installed MATLAB. This will work.